# How to convert Map[A,Future[B]] to Future[Map[A,B]]?

Tags: scala, akka, future

I've been working with the Scala Akka library and have come across a bit of a problem. As the title says, I need to convert `Map[A, Future[B]]` to `Future[Map[A,B]]`. I know that one can use `Future.sequence` for Iterables like Lists, but that doesn't work in this case.

I was wondering: is there a clean way in Scala to make this conversion?

Comment: I'd imagine Scalaz would have a `Traversable` (the Haskell sense of the word) instance for `Map`, which would do exactly what you need.

Comment: @copumpkin Now I will check SO to see if anyone has posted, What is the Haskell sense of the word Traversable?

Comment: See [these](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/jeremy.gibbons/publications/#iterator) [papers](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html) for the original formulation. The Scalaz version is named `Traverse`—see my answer below for how you'd use it here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
val map = Map("a" -> future{1}, "b" -> future{2}, "c" -> future{3})    
val fut = Future.sequence(map.map(entry => entry._2.map(i => (entry._1, i)))).map(_.toMap)
```

The idea is to map the map to an `Iterable` for a `Tuple` of the key of the map and the result of the future tied to that key.  From there you can `sequence` that `Iterable` and then once you have the aggregate `Future`, map it and convert that `Iterable` of `Tuples` to a map via `toMap`.

Now, an alternative to this approach is to try and do something similar to what the `sequence` function is doing, with a couple of tweaks.  You could write a `sequenceMap` function like so:

```
def sequenceMap[A, B](in: Map[B, Future[A]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[Map[B, A]] = {
  val mb = new MapBuilder[B,A, Map[B,A]](Map())
  in.foldLeft(Promise.successful(mb).future) {
    (fr, fa) => for (r <- fr; a <- fa._2.asInstanceOf[Future[A]]) yield (r += ((fa._1, a)))
  } map (_.result)
}
```

And then use it in an example like this:

```
val map = Map("a" -> future{1}, "b" -> future{2}, "c" -> future{3})    
val fut = sequenceMap(map)
fut onComplete{
  case Success(m) => println(m)
  case Failure(ex) => ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

This might be slightly more efficient than the first example as it creates less intermediate collections and has less hits to the `ExecutionContext`.

Comment: In the same spirit:  

`Future.sequence(map map {case (a, b) => b map (a -> _ )}) map (_.toMap)`

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen, you could certainly make it more readable by expanding the code to multiple lines instead of the one liner I submitted.  As far as efficiency, you will incur n+1 additional hits (additional as in above and beyond what happens with `sequence`) to the `ExecutionContext` (the +1 comes from the _.toMap at the end).  Shouldn't be too big a deal, but I will try and post a solution that more mirrors the `sequence` function w/o using it directly for better efficiency in terms of hitting the `ExecutionContext`.

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen, okay, updated with another solution, one that mirrors the existing `sequence` functionality.

Comment: @ChrisGrimm, to the best of my knowledge the combinators on `Future` like `map`, `flatMap`, `recover` etc will not cause blocking behavior.  I believe that each just creates a new `Promise` that is completed in the `onComplete` for the preceeding `Future` and the `Future` from that `Promise` is what's returned as the result of the combinator.  So in essence you are just chaining `onCompletes` together.

Comment: @cmbaxter: Thanks a lot for this answer. It has really helped me to understand the nature of map/flatMap/futures in scala. :)

Comment: +1 I think we should use more builders this way, balanced by DRY etc. I read the first shot yesterday and agree w/comment on readable efficiency.

Comment: Why do you need to write `fa._2.asInstanceOf[Future[A]]`? Why isn’t `fa._2` type already inferred to `Future[A]`?

Comment: @JulienRichard-Foy, good question.  I actually took that code from the source of the scala library `Future.sequence` method and re-purposed it.  That cast is in that code and I left it in there even though it seems it's not necessary.

Comment: See this discussion for an explanation of this cast: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/YpLe7gOvrIo

Answer (score 14):

I think the most succinct we can be with core Scala 2.12.x is

```
val futureMap = Map("a" -> future{1}, "b" -> future{2}, "c" -> future{3}) 

Future.traverse(futureMap.toList) { case (k, fv) => fv.map(k -> _) } map(_.toMap)
```

Comment: Did traverse change overtime? I cannot get this code to work.
I'm on scala 2.12

Comment: @Amiko I updated it. I don't write Scala much anymore so I can't say exactly why it broke. Including this in case it's useful: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/LBTLWYn/0.

Answer (score 9):

Update: You can actually get the nice `.sequence` syntax in [Scalaz 7](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) without too much fuss:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{ Future, future }

import scalaz._, Scalaz.{ ToTraverseOps => _, _ }
import scalaz.contrib.std._

val m = Map("a" -> future(1), "b" -> future(2), "c" -> future(3))
```

And then:

```
scala> m.sequence.onSuccess { case result => println(result) }
Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3)
```

In principle it shouldn't be necessary to hide `ToTraverseOps` like this, but for now it does the trick. See the rest of my answer below for more details about the `Traverse` type class, dependencies, etc.

---

As [copumpkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104136/copumpkin) notes in a comment above, Scalaz contains a [`Traverse` type class](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Traverse.scala) with an instance for `Map[A, _]` that is one of the puzzle pieces here. The other piece is the `Applicative` instance for `Future`, which isn't in Scalaz 7 (which is still cross-built against pre-`Future` 2.9), but is in [`scalaz-contrib`](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-contrib).

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz.contrib.std._

def sequence[A, B](m: Map[A, Future[B]]): Future[Map[A, B]] = {
   type M[X] = Map[A, X]
   (m: M[Future[B]]).sequence
}
```

Or:

```
def sequence[A, B](m: Map[A, Future[B]]): Future[Map[A, B]] =
  Traverse[({ type L[X] = Map[A, X] })#L] sequence m
```

Or:

```
def sequence[A, B](m: Map[A, Future[B]]): Future[Map[A, B]] =
  TraverseOpsUnapply(m).sequence
```

In a perfect world you'd be able to write `m.sequence`, but the `TraverseOps` machinery that  should make this syntax possible isn't currently able to tell how to go from a particular `Map` instance to the appropriate `Traverse` instance.

Comment: Btw, SIP-14 is included in Scala 2.9.3

Answer (score 4):

This also works, where the idea is to use the sequence result (of the map's values) to fire a promise that says you can start retrieving values from your map.  `mapValues` gives you [a non-strict view of your map](http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-037), so the `value.get.get` is only applied when you retrieve the value.  That's right, you get to keep your map!  Free ad for [the puzzlers in that link](http://scalapuzzlers.com).

```
import concurrent._
import concurrent.duration._
import scala.util._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Test extends App {
  def calc(i: Int) = { Thread sleep i * 1000L ; i }
  val m = Map("a" -> future{calc(1)}, "b" -> future{calc(2)}, "c" -> future{calc(3)})
  val m2 = m mapValues (_.value.get.get)
  val k = Future sequence m.values
  val p = Promise[Map[String,Int]]
  k onFailure { case t: Throwable => p failure t }
  k onSuccess { case _ => p success m2 }
  val res = Await.result(p.future, Duration.Inf) 
  Console println res
}
```

Here's the REPL where you see it force the m2 map by printing all its values:

```
scala> val m2 = m mapValues (_.value.get.get)
m2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3)
```

This shows the same thing with futures that are still in the future:

```
scala>   val m2 = m mapValues (_.value.get.get)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
```

Comment: Thanks, @som-snytt! The specific puzzler in this case is [#37](http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-037), as it happens ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just make a new future which waits for all futures in the map values , then builds a map to return.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid using overengineered Scalaz based super-functional solutions (unless your project is already heavily Scalaz based and has tons of "computationally sophisticated" code; no offense on the "overengineered" remark):

```
// the map you have
val foo: Map[A, Future[B]] = ???

// get a Seq[Future[...]] so that we can run Future.sequence on it
val bar: Seq[Future[(A, B)]] = foo.map { case (k, v) => v.map(k -> _) }

// here you go; convert back `toMap` once it completes
Future.sequence(bar).onComplete { data =>
    // do something with data.toMap
}
```

**However**, it should be safe to assume that your map values are somehow generated from the map keys, which initially reside in a `Seq` such as `List`, and that the part of code that builds the initial `Map` is under your control as opposed to being sent from elsewhere. So I would personally take an even simpler/cleaner approach instead by not starting out with `Map[A, Future[B]]` in the first place.

```
def fetchAgeFromDb(name: String): Future[Int] = ???

// no foo needed anymore

// no Map at all before the future completes
val bar = personNames.map { name => fetchAgeFromDb(name).map(name -> _) }

// just as above
Future.sequence(bar).onComplete { data =>
    // do something with data.toMap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this solution acceptable : 
without an execution context this should works ...

```
def removeMapFuture[A, B](in: Future[Map[A, Future[B]]]) = {
  in.flatMap { k =>
    Future.sequence(k.map(l =>
      l._2.map(l._1 -> _)
    )).map {
      p => p.toMap
    }
  }
}
```