# Scala transform Map[Int, Future[Seq[T]]] to Future[Map[Int, Seq[T]]]

Tags: scala

How can I transform a

```
Map[Int, Future[Seq[T]]]
```

to

```
Future[Map[Int, Seq[T]]]
```

in Scala without waiting for the future.

Example:

```
Map( 
  1 -> Future.successful(Seq(100, 200, 300)),
  2 -> Future.successful(Seq(500, 600, 700))
)
```

Comment: Probably `Future.sequence` with a proper `CanBuildFrom`? Or something based on it? (https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L497)

Comment: @GáborBakos I don't think `CanBuildFrom` is necessary here since the `Seq[T]` isn't really being touched.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Map\[A,Future\[B\]\] to Future\[Map\[A,B\]\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479160/how-to-convert-mapa-futureb-to-futuremapa-b)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
val m = Map( 
  1 -> Future.successful(Seq(100, 200, 300)),
  2 -> Future.successful(Seq(500, 600, 700))
)

Future.sequence { m.map { case (i, f) => f.map((i, _))} }.map(_.toMap)
```

Working from the inside out, I mapped the key-values from `(Int, Future[T])` to `Future[(Int, T)]`, then was able to use `Future.sequence` on the resulting sequence of `Future`s. Then that collapsed `Future` can be mapped back to a `Map`.

This can be made slightly shorter using `Future.traverse` as suggested by @IonutG.Stan :

```
Future.traverse(m){ case (i, f) => f.map((i, _))}.map(_.toMap)
```

This will build a new collection within a `Future` from `m`, using the same function provided earlier to map tuples with futures to future tuples.

Comment: You can get rid of the `m.map` call by using `traverse` instead of `sequence`: `Future.traverse(m)({ case (a,b) => b.map(a -> _) }).map(_.toMap)`

Comment: Indeed! That's a little nicer.

Comment: unfortunately I'm using Twitter Futures and Future.traverse as well as Future.sequence is not available to me.

Comment: That's kind of an important thing to mention in the question.. `Future.sequence` is really just a `foldLeft` internally.

Comment: @sonix You should be able to interchange `Future.sequence` with twitter `Futures.collect` relatively easily.