# Scala, execute map of futures

Tags: scala, dictionary, future, for-comprehension

What is the best way to go from

```
Map[String, Future[A]]
```

to

```
Map[String, A]
```

where A is the result of the corresponding future's execution?

This won't compile:

```
val results = for {
  (key, future) <- myMap
  result <- future
} yield (key, result)
```

as I can't mix futures and iterables in the same for comprehension.

Comment: You do realize that to go from `Map[String, Future[A]]` to `Map[String, A]` you will have no choice but to block? Is that OK in your case? Otherwise, I think what you really want is going from `Map[String, Future[A]]` to `Future[Map[String, A]]`

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles good remark. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479160/how-to-convert-mapa-futureb-to-futuremapa-b) contains hints to do that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert it into a `Seq[Future[(String,A)]]`, you can then use [`Future.fold`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@fold) to get it back a single `Future[Map[...]]`:

```
def transform[A](m: Map[String, Future[A]]): Future[Map[String, A]] = {
  val seq: Seq[Future[(String, A)]] = m.toSeq.map { case (key, f) =>
    f.map(i => key -> i)
  }

  Future.fold(seq)(Map.empty[String, A])(_ + _)
}
```

Then redeem the single future as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
 map.mapValues { Await.result(_, 5 seconds) }
```

Comment: Your second alternative does not compile.

Comment: Indeed. Removing it.

Answer (score -1):

Dima already gave an answer using `Await`. However it will raise an exception when the Future fails.

You can further wrap the types inside as a `Try` and then do a `.collect` to filter only for the successful Futures (check out the official API for it).

```
import scala.util.{ Try, Success }

val results = myMap
    .map {
        case (key, value) => key => Try(Await.result(value, 5.seconds))
    }
    .collect {
        case (key, Success(value)) => key -> value
    }
```

With the call above, you automatically discard failing futures and only collect successful ones.

Comment: This won't work: the values in the map are of type  `Future`, which is not compatible with `Success`.  The thing is, you have to block and wait somewhere, to get from `Future` to the actual ("present") result.

Comment: Aha, indeed. I think I'm mixing it with `Try` this time. I've edited my answer. `collect` works only after you retrieve the result somewhere and convert it to an actual `Try`.